# Turning a wheel of a car, stationary vs turning

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

At the end of class, my physics professor left us with a question:

"**Why turning the wheel of a static car is much harder than turning  one in motion?**"

I took the wheel to be a little wide and have a little compressibility so the area of contact would make a rectangle.

Now in the first case turning is opposed by friction on all points on the rectangle (except the one in the center) and in the second it is friction that facilitates turning (which is more on one side to make it turn).

Have I used the right assumptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why turning the wheel of a static car is much harder than turning one in motion

Straight answer is that in a static car you are overcoming static friction and when in motion - rolling resistance. Static friction coefficient for tires is about $50\times$ higher than a [rolling resistance coefficient](http://hpwizard.com/tire-friction-coefficient.html) for same tires.

Comment: I see, but does this also apply to a wheel that is turning?

Comment: IMHO, yes. When you turn wheel in a stationary car, only static and some kinetic friction is at work. But when you turn wheels in a moving car, then there should be only an episodic static friction burst, because you just change direction of movement for the same rolling resistance force.